# Access static variable from "setUpBeforeClass" in "DataProvider" method in php unit test

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.1, phpunit

I am writing my `phpunit test`. I need to initialize a `dataprovider` method to group one of my test. But I am not able to get the static variables declared in the `setUpBeforeClass` method. Those variables are returning `null` to me.

**When did a google search, the documentation said that the `dataprovider` methods will execute before `setUpBeforeClass`.**

Is there any way to override this and make the static variable access from `dataprovider`?

**Sample code**

**setupbefore class function**

```
public static function setUpBeforeClass()
{
    self::sampleVariable = 'Sample Data';
}
```

**dataprovider function**

```
public function sampleDataProvider()
{
    echo self::sampleVariable;
}
```

Comment: could you share a reason for such a need? looks like an intriguing use case..

Answer (score 2):

The reason for data providers to be decoupled from test case setup flow is that they can be defined as external class methods. Also it is about injecting data into tests. Consider such code:

```
class SampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function __construct($name = null, array $data = array(), $dataName = '') {
        parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);
        var_dump('constructed');
    }
    public static function setUpBeforeClass() {
        parent::setUpBeforeClass();
        var_dump('beforeClass');
    }

    public function setUp(){
        var_dump('before');
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider sampleDataProvider
     */
    public function testMethod($expected, $actual) {
        var_dump('test');
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
    }

    public function sampleDataProvider() {
        var_dump('dataProvider');
        return [
            [1, 1],
            [2, 2],
        ];
    }
}
```

when running it, you will notice that first `SampleTest` instance constructed, then dataProvider is invoked, then two instances of `SampleTest` created (one test method times two datasets from dataprovider), then beforeClass method runs, then test method is run twice having datasets from provider injected.

It is not quite clear what your particular use case is but is *might* be possible to refactor the case above into smth like:

```
class AnotherSampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testMethod() {
        foreach ($this->sampleDataProvider() as $dataSet) {
            list($expected, $actual) = $dataSet;
            $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
        }
    }

    public function sampleDataProvider() {
        return [
            [1, 1],
            [2, 2],
        ];
    }
}
```

here `sampleDataProvider` is just a regular method so you are in charge how and when to invoke it, and anyway it gets invoked after `setUpBeforeClass` and `setUp` so it has access to any stuff set up or modified there, so you can make any adjustments needed.

Downside of such approach is that you actually lose splitting one test method into multiple. So it will be one test with multiple asserts comparing to multiple tests with only a few asserts per each. Also you might need to take some extra care about setting up (I mean you might need to refresh smth before each iteration) - solvable by calling `setUp` manually (at first glance).

Don't think it is possible to make any further suggestions without some details on your particular use case.

Comment: > "The reason for data providers to be decoupled from test case setup flow is that they can be defined as external class methods". Ah yeah of course. that didn't occur to me, despite the fact I even *do this* in some of my tests. Duh. Cheers for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

try to declare the variable sampleVariable as 
    static, and check.

```
class MyClass
{  
private static $sampleVariable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way PHPUnit handles data provider methods is weird. They're not called from the same object that the tests are run by, so in the object the DP call is made to, `setupBeforeClass` will not have been run. It's bloody daft IMO, but I'm sure there's a reason it's been done the way it has been done (xmike explains it [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52871545/894061) actually. Not so daft after all ;-).

Given your assignment is just a static value (in yer example anyhow), can you not simply declare it as a class property instead of setting it via `setUpBeforeClass`? I guess the situation might be more complicated that your example demonstrates that prevents this approach: I have only your example to base my suggestions on.

Another thing do do would be to abstract the logic from `setUpBeforeClass` into a separate method, and call that method from both `sampleDataProvider`, and `setUpBeforeClass`.